# Does frequent INSERT/UPDATE query compromise the database safety?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, insert

Hi, I am relatively new to using databases in a web application and I am trying to develop a dynamic application for my users.

So, I was wondering how safe is it to have your application frequently (say every 2 seconds) execute an INSERT/UPDATE query from the same user.

I'm aware that INSERT/UPDATE queries are quite slow to execute (I've read its 12 INSERT per second) but that's not my question.
My question is concerning the safety of my database.

Comment: Well it's highly unlikely to catch fire.

Comment: Actually databases frequently do +25000 inserts and updates per second. Wherever you've read about '12 per second', stop using that source.

Comment: That depends whether or not the queries are safe, i.e `sql injection`. It does not matter how many queries you run per second, just remember to sanitize your input.

Comment: @scheien parameterization, not sanitization ;p

Comment: @MarcGravell Indeed. I was just thinking of little Bobby tables ;-)

Comment: Security of db is not depend upon number of times you run the insert and update query. In order to make your db secure, you should first learn how to avoid SQL injection and make your insert and update statements free of SQL injection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The frequency of executing INSERTs or UPDATEs to your database is in no way related to the `safety` of of your database. But it might impact its `performance`, that's possible.

Answer (score 0):

I think the concern of the OP is more about the robustness of the database's ability to handle load and not become corrupt, rather than issues of SQL injection. (Valuable comments to take note of though).  The volumes suggested per user should no concern.

Database integrity for any DB should be checked with regular maintenance.  Make sure you are doing the following and you should have no problems with performance and reliability.

1. Back up your DB. Full backup and transaction log backups.
2. Re-build and/or Re-Organize indexes
3. Delete old data backups and check free space often.
4. Check the maintenance logs for issues on your DB.

Then monitor performance for sufficient Memory, DISK I/O, and CPU.

Answer (score -1):

wihout "with(nolock)" segment after the table name, the table being insert/update is always locked.

if so, how can it performance well

Comment: nolock typically applies to *read* queries, not write queries; and a single row update most certainly **does not** lock the table. It might take a row lock for a few microseconds, but you'll struggle to notice that. That answer is simply incorrect.